# How to read a string as the name of a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, string, loops

I am trying to concat 12 dataframes. These dataframes are generated by a function (helper) and inputs are named similarly as "m1, m2, m3, m4...,m12". So I wrote down:

```
months = list(range(1,13))
agg = pd.concat([helper(f'm{month}') for month in months])
```

But it seems like the "m1,m2,m3..." are read as strings rather than names of dataframes. How can I iterate these 12 names without letting python read it as strings?

Comment: Show the code of `helper()`. It's returning a string instead of a dataframe.

Comment: Actually I was trying to read m1,m2,m3 as dataframes, which are inputs of helper(). f'm{month}' only output strings.

Comment: "These dataframes are generated by a function (helper)" is what you said in your question. So where _do_ you generate your dataframs? Create a dictionary there that maps strings to the dataframes or just create a list of the dataframes themselves there and don't use strings at all.